# Integral on complex plane

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Does someone has an idea how to calculate:
$$\int_0^\zeta\frac{z^b}{(z-w)^2}dz$$ where $\zeta,w \in \mathbb C$?
I need to compute this integral because I need to solve a differential equation on the complex plane which is:
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z^b}{(z-w)} f(z)\right)=-\frac{z^b}{(z-w)^2} $$
Edit : $z$ is in the unit disk, $0<|w|<1$ and $b=c|w|^2$, $c>1$ is a real constant and I had to remove a half line passing through $0$ so that $z^b$ will be holomorphic.

Comment: Maybe try expanding $1/(z-w)^2$?

Comment: Do you mean Taylor's expansion? Or juste expand $(z-w)^2$ as $z^2+w^2-2zw ?$

Comment: Taylor expansion w.r.t. $z$.

Comment: For $|w|<|z|$, we will have : $$\int_0^\zeta z^{b-2}\sum_n \frac{-2(-2-1)\ldots(-2-n+1)}{n!}\left(\frac{-w}{z}\right)^n ??$$

Comment: And here I just  switch  the integral and  the sum ? And we know how to compute $\int z^\alpha$. But right now the integral will be from $|w|$ to $|z|$ ?

Comment: I have no idea if it will actually work, it was just a suggestion. I was just saying, that would be the first thing I would try out.

Comment: $z \mapsto z^b$ is in general a multi-valued function for complex exponents. Some information about the domain of $z$ and the chosen branch would be helpful.

Comment: To get this differential equation, I just have the condition that $z$ is in the unit disk, $0<|w|<1$ and I had to remove the real half line so $z^b$ will be holomorphic, but I think I can remove any half line of the complex plane and it won't be a problem...

Comment: I suggest to add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{z^b}{(z-w)^2}dz=\frac{x^{b+1}}{(b+1)w^2}\:_2\text{F}_1\left(2\:,\:b+1\:;\:b+2\:;\: \frac{z}{w}\right)+\text{constant}$$
$\:_2\text{F}_1(A,B;C;X)$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function
$$\int_0^\zeta\frac{z^b}{(z-w)^2}dz=\frac{\zeta^{b+1}}{(b+1)w^2}\:_2\text{F}_1\left(2\:,\:b+1\:;\:b+2\:;\: \frac{\zeta}{w}\right)\qquad \text{if}\quad b>-1$$